# Microsoft Word: Place a footnote in the margin

Tags: microsoft-word, margins, footnote, footers

Microsoft Word has the ability to place a footer in the page's margin.  This is very useful when writing documents that must meet exact rules or page counts (e.g. government work).

Is there a way to do so for a footnote? Specifically, if I want to place an asterisk on a section label, and have the footnote for that asterisk show up in the bottom margin of the page (where the footer is) - How can I do that?